# Magento 2 : Is there a way to customize the labels of an admin form toggle?

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, uicomponent, checkbox, toggle

For admin form UI checkbox components that use the 'toggle' (like Catalog > Product > [product record] > Enabled) - I can see a few references to the UI component configuration using:

```
<field name="my_field">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
             <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">15</item>
             <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">boolean</item>
             <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">checkbox</item>
             <item name="prefer" xsi:type="string">toggle</item>
             <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Enabled</item>
             <item name="valueMap" xsi:type="array">
                  <item name="true" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                  <item name="false" xsi:type="string">0</item>
             </item>
             <item name="default" xsi:type="string">1</item>
        </argument>
     </field>
```

That'll give me the little toggle with the 'Yes / No' labels - is it possible to change the 'Yes / No' to something else? (Active / Inactive)

Comment: yes,it can be done.

Comment: Please check the edit of my answer, it is working!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>The labels cannot be changed within the uiComponent options but if you want to override the core functionality , you will have to override</strike>

It can be done, check edit.

```
vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/form/element/single-checkbox.js
```

The yes/no value is returned by following block of code @line 57 of above file

```
if (this.prefer === 'toggle' && _.isEmpty(this.toggleLabels)) {
                this.toggleLabels = {
                    'on': $t('Yes'),
                    'off': $t('No')
                };
            }
```

**EDIT :**

So, I was not able to find example for **toggleLabels** in core but managed to figure it out by code above .

Just add this node to your component ;

```
<item name="toggleLabels" xsi:type="array">
           <item name="on" xsi:type="string">Active</item>
           <item name="off" xsi:type="string">Inactive</item>
</item>
```

You can replace Active and Inactive to whatever desired string .

Resultant xml  will be ;

```
<field name="my_field">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
             <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">15</item>
             <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">boolean</item>
             <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">checkbox</item>
             <item name="prefer" xsi:type="string">toggle</item>
             <item name="toggleLabels" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="on" xsi:type="string">Active</item>
               <item name="off" xsi:type="string">Inactive</item>
             </item>
             <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Enabled</item>
             <item name="valueMap" xsi:type="array">
                  <item name="true" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                  <item name="false" xsi:type="string">0</item>
             </item>
             <item name="default" xsi:type="string">1</item>
        </argument>
     </field>
```

Comment: he has asked using Ui-component section may be but you have given with js

Comment: @Learing_Coder , I have added uiComponent code in edit.

Comment: Thanks @VivekKumar! using toggleLabels in the UI Component xml worked

Comment: Np @NathanBennett , consider +1 the answer if you think it addressed all your issues.

Comment: how can i override/change  the default label which is coming from vendor ui component files